# Documentation for nuget API

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, nugetgallery

does anyone knows a good documentation for nuget service endpoints?

I'm looking for it for both nuget v2 and v3 (v2 in priority as V3 is still in contruction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating several years later: There is now official documentation for the NuGet server API over at [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation of NuGet API, but since NuGet is open source, you can take a look here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery

The API requests handling code is located in this file:
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/src/NuGetGallery/Controllers/ApiController.cs